# Group and Aggregate with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a timesheet entries as below

**ActivityCode : Duration**

---

- Project A: 12h:31mins
- Project B: 00h:10mins
- Project A: 01h:10mins
- Project A: 12h:31mins
- Project C: 12h:31mins
- Project B: 00h:10mins
- Project B: 01h:10mins
- Project A: 12h:31mins

What is the correct way to **group the projects** and **aggregate** their total time spent? i'm trying the below

```
    var summary = from entry in DbSet
                  where entry.Timesheet.UserID == userid &&
                  entry.Timesheet.DateSubmitted >= startdate &&
                  entry.Timesheet.DateSubmitted <= enddate
                  group entry by entry.ActivityCode.ActivityCode1
                      into groupEntry
                      select new TimeSheetSummary()
                      {
                          ActivityCode = groupEntry.Key,
                          HourSpent = Convert.ToInt32(groupEntry.Sum(x => x.Duration)),
                          Percentage = (Convert.ToInt32(groupEntry.Sum(x => x.Duration)) / 8) * 100,
                          MinuteSpent = Convert.ToInt32(groupEntry.Sum(x => x.Duration)) * 60,
                      };
```

Comment: haven't tried it but i'm thinking if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Try it and if it gives you an exception, update your question with the details.

Comment: i'm quite sure the Percentage calculation is wrong cause it's hardcoded to divive by 8 projects but instead it should be divided by number of groupentry.

Comment: tried. i have error "ActivityCode = groupEntry.Key;" cannot convert type "int" to type "xx.xxx.ActivityCode"

Comment: HourSpent should be the total / 60 and MinuteSpent should be the total mod 60

Comment: how do i find the ActivityCode object in LINQ? i'm getting "ActivityCode = groupEntry.Key;" cannot convert type "int" to type "xx.xxx.ActivityCode"

Comment: groupEntry.Key is being set to the value of entry.ActivityCode.ActivityCode1.  If the ActivityCode in the TimeSheetSummary view model isn't the same type as entry.ActivityCode.ActivityCode1, maybe your group by phrase should be `group entry by entry.ActivityCode` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a percentage, get a count of the number of activites and use that to divide by.

Not sure if you will need a divide by 0 check here.  I'm not sure what the second LINQ will do if there's no data to begin with.  Not sure if that would raise an error or not.

```
Int32 numberOfProjects = (from entry in DbSet
              where entry.Timesheet.UserID == userid &&
                  entry.Timesheet.DateSubmitted >= startdate &&
                  entry.Timesheet.DateSubmitted <= enddate
              select entry.ActivityCode.ActivityCode1).Distinct().Count();

var summary = from entry in DbSet
              where entry.Timesheet.UserID == userid &&
              entry.Timesheet.DateSubmitted >= startdate &&
              entry.Timesheet.DateSubmitted <= enddate
              group entry by entry.ActivityCode.ActivityCode1
                  into groupEntry
                  select new TimeSheetSummary()
                  {
                      ActivityCode = groupEntry.Key,
                      HourSpent = Convert.ToInt32(groupEntry.Sum(x => x.Duration)),
                      Percentage = (Convert.ToInt32(groupEntry.Sum(x => x.Duration)) / numberOfProjects) * 100,
                      MinuteSpent = Convert.ToInt32(groupEntry.Sum(x => x.Duration)) * 60,
                  };
```

Comment: how to get only the projects that is involve? I mean "numberOfProjects" is now consider all projects in the table, what if i want only projects that user perform on the certain timeframe with this consideration into account Timesheet.UserID TimeSheet.TimeSheetDate

Comment: Oh, duh, forgot to filter on the date range :)

Comment: how do i find the ActivityCode object in LINQ? i'm getting "ActivityCode = groupEntry.Key;" cannot convert type "int" to type "xx.xxx.ActivityCode"

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i found as answer based on the inputs by others in the thread. thanks!

```
    var groupEntries = from entry in DbSet
                       where entry.Timesheet.UserID == userId &&
                             entry.Timesheet.TimeSheetDate <= endDate.Date &&
                             entry.Timesheet.TimeSheetDate >= startDate.Date
                       group entry by entry.ActivityCode
                           into groupEntry
                           select new
                           {
                               ActivityCode = groupEntry.Key,
                               Duration = Convert.ToInt16(groupEntry.Sum(r => r.Duration))
                           };

    var totalDuration = groupEntries.Sum(r => r.Duration);

    var result = from groupEntry in groupEntries
                 select new TimeSheetSummary()
                            {
                                ActivityCode = groupEntry.ActivityCode,
                                HourSpent = groupEntry.Duration / 60,
                                MinuteSpent = groupEntry.Duration % 60,
                                Percentage = groupEntry.Duration / totalDuration * 100
                            };
```